# Does encrypting your script affect performance much?

Tags: php, encryption

I have been building an application, in my spare time, for a while now and have been thinking about how to protect my product from piracy (it will be something that the customers will have on their server).

I have been checking out the various encryption products around and they seem to be do the trick.

But, I how much will it slow down my site?

Comment: Have you tried any side-by-side performance analysis? That would be a good place to start. A WORD OF CAUTION: If you do not want your code to be stolen, do not make it available on the Internet.

Comment: Well, if you have official customers with webservers (as opposed to any random bloke on the internet with some webspace), you could just license your code and legally bind them to not steal it. It's not going to really stop them if they really want to, but neither would encryption. Companies/businesses, in general, don't really like to steal stuff as resulting legal action is likely to be costly.

Comment: I second what Vld says, your better off just licensing then trying to encrypt. Most php encryption works on obfuscating and then base 64 encoding, to then decode and eval. A malicious user can get past this very easily. If someone who has access to your software wants to steal it, chances are you cant stop them.

Comment: If I was paying you for this application, why would I "steal" it? If I wasn't paying you, I wouldn't take closed-source/encrypted code and run it on my servers. Either way, you're barking up the wrong tree.

Comment: @deceze In all fairness, there is the chance that, for example, I pay to OP for the application, get it, then give you the code. Or maybe I then change the code and resell it to other people. Or I integrate it into some platform I have. And so on and so forth. Basically, yeah - you could both pay for the code and steal it. But it's not really a technical issue as much as legal, thus my suggestion for licensing.

Comment: You did not mention, what products you are using. Could you elaborate? I am interested in them as well.

Answer (score 1):

It is currently not possible to let encrypted general programs run on customer machines (see *On the (Im)possibility of Obfuscating Programs* by Barak, Goldreich, Impagliazzo and Rudich).

What you probably mean is code obfuscation which is **not** encryption in any way. Most likely there is no performance hit when you use them in the same way as JavaScript runs in the same way when minified.